# Is $f(n,m) = 2n-m$ onto?

Tags: functions

I'm having trouble determining if a function is onto.

The function is $$\begin{align}\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} &\to \mathbb{Z}\\ (m,n) &\mapsto 2n - m\end{align}$$

I know it's not one-one because if you use $(m,n) = (1,1)$ and $(3,2)$ they both equal $1$, but I'm not sure how to go about proving if it's onto or not.

Comment: Notice that $f(m,0)=-m$.

Comment: And because that's an integer it's onto?

Answer (score 3):

Let $m \in \Bbb Z$. Then:

$$f(m,m) = 2m - m = m$$

Since $m$ was arbitrary, we find that $f$ is onto.

---

That was admittedly a tad *deus ex machina*. In a more procedural fashion, we might do it as follows:

> Let $k \in \Bbb Z$. Then we need to solve $2n - m = k$.
>
> That is to say, $m = 2n - k$, and we find $f(2n - k, n) = k$.

Thus we can get $f(m,n) = k$ whatever $n$ is. Now we can get back our original answer by the special choice $n = k$.

Answer (score 2):

So given an integer $k$ is there a pair $(m,n)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ such that $f(m,n)=k$?

$$f(-k,0)=2\cdot0-(-k)=k.$$

So every integer is in the range of $f$.

Comment: That makes sense. Can I put k in either spot (m,n) assuming it works out.

Comment: Oops I've got it backwards, will edit.